# Show unbound keys

Tags: key-bindings

I want to define some key bindings for my new found usage of helm, amazing mode btw, and I want to do it without overwriting the usage of other keys. I realize that the number of different key combinations is infinite, but is there some way to see all *undefined* key bindings for say 1 level deep?

For example, I want to know what key bindings are available after hitting `C-c`, and then get a buffer with a listing of `C-c some_keys`.

Assuming this feature doesn't currently exist?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Check out the [`free-keys`](https://github.com/Fuco1/free-keys) package, which gives you a function of the same name that shows you all your currently unused key-bindings.

[`bind-key`](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package/blob/master/bind-key.el) is also a helpful tool which gives you a cleaner syntax for defining your own bindings, i.e.:

```
(bind-key "C-h C-k" 'free-keys)
```

`bind-key` also comes with a handy defun called `describe-personal-keybindings` to see all the key-bindings you've set as well as if and what bindings you've overridden.

Answer (score 9):

Here are few ideas. They don't answer your question directly but they can help you figure out which key bindings are available for use.

## Get a list of all key bindings starting with a prefix

The [`guide-key`](https://github.com/kai2nenobu/guide-key) package can be used to show, in alphabetical order, all the key bindings that begin with the entered prefix.

The below screen capture shows `guide-key` showing me all my key-bindings beginning with <kbd>C-x r</kbd>. As the available bindings are listed alphabetically, it's easy to figure out which bindings are available.

The screen capture also shows what other key prefixes I use `guide-key` for.

[image: My key bindings that begin with C-x r]

## Get a list of what bindings you overrode

The `describe-personal-keybindings` function that comes with the [`use-package`](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package) package shows what key bindings you overrode as shown in below screen capture. You can review the results of this function to check if you overrode a binding unintentionally. The cool thing is that this function shows the bindings for all minor modes too.

[image: Sample of what the output of describe-personal-keybindings looks like]

Answer (score 7):

You can hit `C-c C-h` to know all bindings that start with `C-c`. This works for any key sequence that is "incomplete": hit that key sequence and then `C-h` to see all the keybindings that start with that sequence. You can then pick something not in the list.

To know whether a particular keybinding is defined (to avoid overwriting it), you can use `C-h c` or `M-x describe-key-briefly` (or `C-h k` or `M-x describe-key`) to see what it is defined to, in the current mode.

Answer (score 1):

[**Icicles** key completion](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Key_Completion) - `S-TAB` - shows you all key sequences currently available for use (i.e., bound, not free), including after you hit a prefix key.

For example, `C-x r S-TAB` shows key sequences with the prefix `C-x r`.

Keys that are not listed are unbound (free).

You can sort the displayed key sequences in different ways, using `C-,`.